# Creating a zipped list of two lists in Python, but allowing duplicates from one list to the other

Tags: python

Using `itertools` and `permutation()` to get all unique combinations of two lists is easy. For instance, if I had:

```
['a', 'b']
[1, 2]
```

I could easily get:

```
[
  [('a',1),('b',2)],
  [('a',2),('b',1)]
]
```

However, what I really want is to allow duplicate pairings. Each item in the larger list will be unique, but the number of combinations would be exponential, since the same item in the first list could get assigned to multiple items in the second list. So for the two lists above, I would get:

```
[
  [('a',1),('a',2)],
  [('a',1),('b',2)],
  [('b',1),('a',2)]
  [('b',1),('b',2)]
]
```

If I had three items in each of the two lists, I would end up with 27 results. What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: You are looking for `itertools.product`, not `itertools.permutation`

Comment: you want the *cartesian product*

Comment: I don't believe it does. If I code:

```
x = [["a", "b", "c"], [1, 2, 3]]
import itertools

for element in itertools.product(*x):
    print(element)
```

I get 9 pairs. What I'm really looking for is 27 lists with three elements per list:

```
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('a', 3)],
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)],
[('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('c', 3)],
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)],
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3)],
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)],
[('a', 1), ('c', 2), ('a', 3)],
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, product
>>> x = ['a', 'b']
>>> y = [1, 2]
>>> list(combinations(product(x, y), 2))
[(('a', 1), ('a', 2)),
 (('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
 (('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
 (('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
 (('a', 2), ('b', 2)),
 (('b', 1), ('b', 2))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = list(itertools.combinations(list(itertools.product(x,y)),2))
list_2 = [i for i in list_1 if i[0][1] != i[1][1]]

print(list_2)
```

Output

```
[(('a', 1), ('a', 2)),
 (('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
 (('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
 (('b', 1), ('b', 2))]
```